# Datatables sorting and filtering in the <thead> element

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatable

I'm using [Datatables](https://datatables.net) to sort / filter a table of data I have. I'd like to be able to sort and filter both in the header, however, the click to filter makes the table sort and the filter select then does not stay open.

I have a demo here: http://codepen.io/jasonflaherty/pen/xOdqVV using this type of idea:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th><span class="header">Name</span><span class="filter"></span></th>
      <th><span class="header">Position</span><span class="filter"></span></th>
      <th><span class="header">Office</span><span class="filter"></span></th>
      <th><span class="header">Age</span><span class="filter"></span></th>
      <th><span class="header">Start date</span><span class="filter"></span></th>
      <th><span class="header">Salary</span><span class="filter"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Is there a way to take the bSort click off the entire th element and make it just work on a class="header" for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) function to remove the `click` event from `<th>` tag. Then add new event handler to the element which you want to, in that event handler, you can call DataTables API [`columns().order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().order()).

Base on your code, added this after append options to select:

```
// your code
column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
  select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
});

// new code here
// remove original event handler
$(column.header()).off('click');

// register new event handler
$(column.header()).on('click', function(e) {
  // check click target is "<span class='header'>...</span>" or not
  if (e.target.nodeName !== 'SPAN' || !$(e.target).hasClass('header'))
    return;

  // call DataTables API to sort this column and redraw this table
  column
    .order($(this).hasClass('sorting_desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc')
    .draw();
});
```

Note: if you just want the `<select>` tag do not trigger sort event. you can add a `click` event handler to `<select>` element to stop event bubbling.

For example:

```
var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
  .appendTo($(column.header()).find('span.filter').empty())
  .on({
    'change': function() {
      // Do something
    },
    'click': function(e) {
      // stop click event bubbling
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: The e.stopPropagation(); on the select worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I just spent hours going the wrong direction on this and your solution works perfectly. Thanks!